# MySQL default current_timestamp + 1 year

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I make a simple table with id and date with default value CURRENT_TIMESTAMP and i am curious how to set date CURRENT_TIMESTAMP + 1 year. For example if NOW() is 2018-01-23 13:57:22 i want as default value to be 2019-01-23 13:57:22. I can made this with trigger or with code before insert new line but is there other shortcut?

For example: How can i set as default value DATE_ADD(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, INTERVAL 1 YEAR)

Same problem with this: https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=56835

Comment: You can write a trigger to set the date like that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It cant be [manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/data-type-defaults.html).

> The DEFAULT value clause in a data type specification indicates a
>   default value for a column. With one exception, the default value must
>   be a constant; it cannot be a function or an expression. This means,
>   for example, that you cannot set the default for a date column to be
>   the value of a function such as NOW() or CURRENT_DATE. The exception
>   is that you can specify CURRENT_TIMESTAMP as the default for TIMESTAMP
>   and DATETIME columns.

So the only way right now is with trigger or manually before insert new line in table.